# Create Custom Entry Point in Vtiger CRM & Call without Auth

Tags: sugarcrm, vtigercrm

Actually i want SSO in Vtiger CRM with 3rd Paty application  . 
For example if i log in in the application , i want to login the same user in the Vtiger Also.
I have done this thing with SugarCRM and SuiteCRM using entry point , but need some help to do this with VtigerCRM.

Please help me to make a entry point in Vtiger CRM as we make in SugarCRM , In Sugar CRM we can make a custom entry point and call it from anywhere by doing Auth=false .

Is there any way possible to do this in Vtiger CRM ???

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution for this .

**this is the URL to use to login automatically for version v6.x.x**

http://youhost/vtigercrm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login&username=youruser&password=yourpassword

**it's some little difference with version 5.x.x**

http://yourhost/vtigercrm/index.php?module=Users&action=Authenticate&return_module=Users&return_action=Login&user_name=YOURUSER&user_password=YOURPASSWORD